# Alert Notification When a Scheduled Job is deleted from Scheduled Jobs in Salesforce

Tags: apex, email-alert, scheduled-job

Is there any way to alert the Admin user (like sending Email Notification) if any scheduled job is deleted from Scheduled Jobs?

Answer (score 2):

If you say any direct process then there is no standard process is available, but there is a work around by which i think you can achieve this functionality

1. create on **Batch class** and schedule it after you **schedule job** is .
2. In that batch class run the below query:

   ```
   SELECT Id,JobType,Name FROM CronJobDetail where Name='you scheduled
   job Name'
   ```
3. then with the help of Job Id query on  **CronTrigger**

   ```
   SELECT CreatedById, CreatedDate, 
   CronExpression, CronJobDetailId, EndTime, Id, NextFireTime,
   PreviousFireTime,StartTime,State,TimesTriggered
   FROM CronTrigger where CronJobDetailId :='your job Id from above query'
   ```
4. Now put the logic after that if the job is already deleted you can check this from the query and send email based on the logic.

Comment: @sunny, is it working for u?

Comment: very helpful @avijit